# Help with certain limit

Tags: limits

so I am trying to solve this equation:
$$\lim_{\to\infty }\sqrt[n]{5^n-20n^2}$$

I tried it like this, but it is wrong:
$\lim_{\to\infty }\sqrt[n]{5^n-20n^2}=\lim_{\to\infty }\sqrt[n]{5^n(1-\frac{20n^2}{5^n})}=5$

I now know I have to use the "enclosed sequence sentence" (forgive me if the name is wrong, english isnt my first language).

So I started like this:

$lower\le \lim_{\to\infty }\sqrt[n]{5^n-20n^2}\le 5$

I cant find the limit that would be lower than $\lim_{\to\infty }\sqrt[n]{5^n-20n^2}$ and give me the solution.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: You should just take 5 outside before taking the limit

Comment: You mean like this?
$5\lim_{\to\infty }\sqrt[n]{1-\frac{20n^2}{5^n}}$

Answer (score 1):

Observe that

$$\sqrt[n]{5^n-20n^2}\ge \sqrt[n]{5^n-5^{n-1}}\iff5^n-20n^2\ge5^n-5^{n-1}\stackrel{\cdot(-1)}\iff$$

$$5\cdot4n^2\le 5^{n-1}\iff 4n^2\le 5^{n-2}$$

and the last inequality is easily provable for $\;n\ge5\;$ , say by induction, and also

$$\sqrt[n]{5^n-5^{n-1}}=5\sqrt[n]{1-\frac15}\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}5$$

so now you can use the squeeze theorem:

$$\sqrt[n]{5^n-5^{n-1}}\sqrt[n]{5^n-20n^2}\le\sqrt[n]{5^n}=5$$

Comment: That was very helpful, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

We have

$\sqrt[n]{5^n-20n^2}=5\sqrt[n]{1-20\frac{n^2}{5^n}}$

let us find

$\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{n^2}{5^n}=$

$=\lim_{n\to \infty}n^2e^{-nln(5)}=L=?$

taking logarithm, we get

$n(2\frac{ln(n)}{n}-ln(5))$ wich goes to $-\infty$

since $\lim_{n\to+\infty}\frac{ln(n)}{n}=0$.

thus $L=0$

and your limit is then $5.1^0=5$.